# ColdFusion: new cfid with every refresh

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I updated a test server from ColdFusion 10 to ColdFusion 11 30 days Enterprise trail edition with update 7.

However, every time I hit refresh in my browsers, I get a new cfid.
As a result, a valid session is not found so the login page doesn't work.

I checked the session in coldfusion admin page and my cookie in my browsers, they are both created correctly.

This is what I have in my application.cfm

```
<CFAPPLICATION NAME="TESTWEB"
  CLIENTMANAGEMENT="Yes"
  SETCLIENTCOOKIES="Yes"
  SESSIONMANAGEMENT="Yes"
  SESSIONTIMEOUT = "#CreateTimeSpan(7,0,0,0)#"
  SETDOMAINCOOKIES = "No">
```

**However**, when I open the page from the host computer, then the cfid doesn't get change everytime I hit refresh, so everything works.

Any idea what can cause my problem?

EDIT:

1. During login, I had code that set cfid/cftoken to cookie, but since I changed to SETCLIENTCOOKIES="Yes", I removed those code. The only other place would be in logout.
2. I am not using jsessionids, only coldFusion session id.
3. Timeout for all session variables is 7 days.

Comment: Do you have any code in place that manipulates the session - say rewriting the cfid/cftoken or managing the jsessionid?  Are you using jsessionids? and finally what is the Max" timeout setting in the cfadmin for these vars?

Comment: Does your browser keep the `CFID` and `CFTOKEN` cookies properly and submits them in subsequent requests?

Comment: Also make sure the `sessionTimeout` is properly set in the ColdFusion server admin as the global setting will cap any value set on application level (`<cfapplication>` and `Application.cfc`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have switched to using JEE session by enabling it in the ColdFusion admin. My session is now working.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I'll leave this here to help others in case they've tried everything mentioned above and are still having issues.

**Check your Cookie Samesite value.**

If you've upgrading old apps to newer CF servers, to prevent Coldfusion from changing CFID and CFTOKEN on refresh or when you make an AJAX call referencing sessions or cookie variables - along with all the recommended settings stated by others above, check to following:

**To set Cookie Samesite value at server level for CF 2016, 2018:**
In the Coldfusion Admin Settings, Server Settings > Memory Variables > Session Cookie Settings, Set the "Cookie Samesite default value" to "-" or "LAX" (LAX is default value when NULL)

**To set Cookie Samesite value at site level:** 
*For ColdFusion (2018 release) Update 9 and ColdFusion (2016 release) Update 15*
You may use the cfcookie tag.

**For those on CF11 or older CF versions,** you may set your response headers in IIS or Apache. I am assuming people with this issue (cfid and cftoken changing on refresh) is because they made a change to the samesite attribute and broke something. In that case, review how you've implemented SameSite Cookies and what you set that value to.

[SameSite Cookies with IIS](https://www.petefreitag.com/item/850.cfm)
[SameSite cookies with Apache](https://www.petefreitag.com/item/894.cfm)